How can we discuss the "divergent-ness" of an infinite series?
There are many infinite series that converge "regularly" to a finite value, such as the geometric series
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^n} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots = 2. $$
Meanwhile, there are also infinite series which are divergent, such as the Grandi series
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n = 1-1+1-1+\cdots $$
or the sum of natural numbers
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1}n = 1+2+3+\cdots. $$
However, I learned that with the appropriate summation methods, we can assign finite values to these traditionally divergent sums. For example, the Grandi series can be summed in the Cesàro $(C,1)$ sense, giving a value of $\frac{1}{2}$:
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n = 1-1+1-1+\cdots = \frac{1}{2} \; (C,1), $$
while the natural numbers is not $(C,1)$-summable, nor $(C,\alpha)$-summable for that matter, but can be summed using zeta function regularisation:
$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1}n = 1+2+3+\cdots = -\frac{1}{12}. $$
It occurs to me that some of these summation methods are "stronger" than others, in the sense that a stronger summation method may assign a finite sum to a divergent series where the weaker method fails, so say zeta function regularisation would be stronger than Cesàro $(C,\alpha)$-summation. In this sense, it feels to me as though the sum of natural numbers, which can only be summed by a method "stronger" than the one needed to sum the Grandi series, is more divergent, while the Grandi series is less divergent.
So I'm curious, is this concept of "divergent-ness" of infinite series defined in the mathematics literature?

The wikipedia article covers the standard sort of "regularity' properties one might hope for (though doesn't always get).  Also, Hardy has a very interesting book on Divergent Series.

A series is divergent iff it is not convergent. Sometimes , we distinguish between oscillating series and series diverging to $\infty$ or to $-\infty$. Note that $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$ is plain wrong ! The regularization is NOT the sum , the same holds for the other regularizations.
